# position image in center square and fill the remaining space with colour

Tags: html, css

I want to position an image into a center square and fill in the remaining space with colour. With the below code though, my image is on top and the text "test" is right below the image. I want the text to be outside the 120x120 square.

I tried the below code:

CSS (included in head):

```
.img-container {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#000;
}
.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="img-container" href="http://google.com"><img src="http://couponcoupon.biz/image/logo/landmsupply.com.jpg" /> Test </a>
```

Comment: Can you create an picture to see what you want exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/
It has a great breakdown of absoulte center:

```
.Absolute-Center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

A fiddle with it applied to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/XgNXa/
I also moved the text down with a negative bottom: setting.  I'm not wild about it, I'd add a wrapper div around the img-container a to have the text below it, but I didn't want to change your markup too much.

```
.img-container span {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left:0;right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in a `<span>` then use CSS to move it around

Make sure your `.img-container` has `position:relative;` set and remove `overflow:hidden;`, then do this

```
.img-container span {
    position:absolute;
    left:125px;
```

your text will be wherever you want it.

As for the image being in the center.  If it is a dynamic image (changing all the time) You will have to either experiment with `display:table-cell` or look into some javascript.  If the image is the same one every time, you can just `position` it inside your img-container with `position:absolute`, `top:45px` or wherever center is.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's a typo in your example

```
height: 100%px;
```

this must be either `100%` or `100px`, but not both.

You can use `background-image` and `background-position` to center the image

CSS:

```
.img-container {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(http://couponcoupon.biz/image/logo/landmsupply.com.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

To move the text below the square, remove `overflow: hidden` and add a `margin` to a wrapper around the text

HTML:

```
<a class="img-container" href="http://google.com">
    <div class="center">Test</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container .center {
    margin: 120px 45px;
}
```

Complete [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3C5KE/)